# How to tell if a window failed to close in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

Is there a way in Electron to tell if a window was not successfully closed?

```
win.once("closed", () => {
    // send message to the page running in the renderer process that the window was closed
});

win.close();
```

Assuming that I'm not cancelling the close in the `close` or `beforeunload` handler, can the window still fail to close, or can I be sure that a message will always be sent to the guest page?

Answer (score 1):

I just came to this issue as well, what I did is simply wait for a few hundred milliseconds, if the callback is called, then most likely, this window has failed to close:

```js
win.on('close', () => setTimeout(() => console.log('failed to close'), 300))
```

Comment: I think that only works if the window is the main window and you've set your app to quit out when the window has closed. In my case, the windows were just random secondary windows, so I don't think this'll work

Comment: @pushkin I just tested, if you apply the above to all windows (e.g. through recursion), the console will log `failed to close` for any window if that window has failed to close. _"you've set your app to quit out when the window has closed"_ `app.close` and `app.quit` are two separate functions, and the question didn't mention quitting, so I'm not sure what you meant here.

Comment: why does the callback being called mean that the window failed to close?

Comment: @pushkin In most cases, it won't be called if the window closes successfully.

Comment: @pushkin It's an indirect way for detecting a failed closure, to my limited knowledge, there's no direct way for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#winclosed) property in the doc:

> `win.closed`
>
> A Boolean that is set to true after the child window gets closed.

And [this](http://win.closed%20A%20Boolean%20that%20is%20set%20to%20true%20after%20the%20child%20window%20gets%20closed.) other bit too:

> `win.destroy()`
>
> Force closing the window, the unload and beforeunload
>   event won’t be emitted for the web page, and close event will also not
>   be emitted for this window, but it guarantees the closed event will be
>   emitted.

With that, you should have all the info you need to create a function that insure you that the window closes:

```js
function forceClose(window) {
  
  // try close first
  window.close()
  
  // force with destroy
  if(!window.closed) {
    window.destroy()
  }
  
  //just logging out the event
  window.on('closed', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
  
}


// in your code, instead of calling win.close()
forceClose(win)
```

Comment: But the flag is set to true only *after* the `closed` event fires, right? So if for whatever reason, the `closed` event still hasn't fired by the time we get to the `if (!window.closed)` check, we'll have an issue. I was hoping there was some kind of event that got fired if there was a problem creating the window.

Comment: Creating the window or closing the window? Maybe I misunderstood your question "can the window still fail to close". You can put a log in that `if` node, which would let you know if there was a problem with `win.close()` (and you deal with it), but destroy will *always* close the window

Comment: There are events that you can listen for when a window is created, you just have to examine the events object to see the details: https://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#event-browser-window-created

Comment: @kuzyin My bad, I meant "closing the window."

Comment: "put a log in that `if` node, which would let you know if there was a problem" - My point above still stands. If I understand the docs you linked to correctly, the `closed` flag isn't set immediately when you call `close()`, but when the `closed` event fires, which would happen after `close`, `beforeUnload`, etc. events are fired and handled, which happens asynchronously. The implication is that `closed` may be `false` simply because the `closed` event hasn't fired yet.

Comment: The code above make sure that the window is closed, it does not track the lifecycle of the window. As you said, if you want to do that you can simply listen for the `close`, `beforeUnload`, `unload` *and* `closed` events and get confirmation at each steps. You are also right about the possible race condition, but it does not really matter since `window.closed` will always be true (whether from `window.close()` or `window.destroy()`

Comment: Actually, `window.close` does not fires `beforeUnload` and `unload` https://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#winclose

Comment: I think I see the solution; correct me if I'm wrong. The only difference between the functions `close` and `destroy` is that `destroy` only fires the `closed` event, so there no chance that a `beforeUnload` handler, for instance, cancels the event. It seems like the only way that `win.close` can "fail" is if I tell it to cancel in one of those handlers. Thus, I think that I can safely send back a "the window closed" response whenever I call `win.close()` assuming that I'm not cancelling it. Alternatively, I can just always call `win.destroy()`. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yep, that sounds right but I would still send back "the window closed" after the `closed` event has been sent: you don't know what might happen between the close and you showing it. Another small note, is that `window.close()` spawn the `close` and `closed` event while `window.destroy()` only spawn the `closed` event. As for the `beforeUnload`/`unload` events, they are only send out when we close the windows with the gui/mouse.